# Write R Data direct via Console

Tags: r, terminal

Whats the most effective way to write a R Datasample direct in to a File:

In Terminal, typing `"R" -> R` works.

Creating a Datsample:
`sample(1.00:20000.00, 10)`

How could I write the result direct in to a file?
I know the (normal) method:

(e.g.) `ls -l > ~/Directory/file.txt`

But the `>` and `>>` approach is the wrong way in R Console.

Comment: Did you try [write.table](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `capture.output`:

```
capture.output(sample(1.00:20000.00, 10),
             file='~/Directory/file.txt')
```

This will create a file with the same output as what you see in the console.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, explore `sink`. Here's a minimal example. In it, we tell R to start sinking the output to a file. The output is not visible in the R console here.

```
set.seed(1)
sink(file="sinking.txt")
sample(1.00:20000.00, 10)
sink()
```

The second call to `sink()` stops sinking the output to a file. The output shows up in the R console as expected.

```
sample(1.00:20000.00, 10)
# [1]  4120  3531 13740  7681 15394  9952 14349 19832  7598 15542
```

`sink` has other arguments too. `append` lets you add values to an existing file, and `split` makes it so that the output is sent to ***both*** the R console and the file. Now, we'll resume writing to the previous file. Set it to append the output to the previous file, and to display the output in the console

```
sink(file="sinking.txt", append=TRUE, split=TRUE)
sample(letters, 10)
#  [1] "y" "f" "p" "c" "z" "i" "a" "h" "x" "v"
sink()
```

Let's read the file back in and see what was written.

```
cat(readLines("sinking.txt"), sep = "\n")
#  [1]  5311  7443 11456 18162  4033 17964 18888 13212 12578  1236
#  [1] "y" "f" "p" "c" "z" "i" "a" "h" "x" "v"
```